# XNA Framework (MonoGame) GraphicsDevice.Clear (alpha?)

Tags: xna, monogame

I'm learning XNA, little stuck. I need a fade from 255 black to transparent, can I achieve this by using `GraphicsDevice.Clear` method?

Comment: Adjusting the color's alpha channel is as easy as modifying a property's value in the Color struct instance passed to the Clear method.  However, clearing with a transparent color will cause the actual color on the screen to be black. Therefore, you obviously wouldn't notice any change in fading from black to transparent.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. Try adding a little more detail about what you expect the end result to be.